# Assets do not load but when I hot reload

Tags: image, flutter, assets, hot-reload, flutter-hotreload

I am new to flutter. I am getting image from backend and displaying those images on the screen using Hero and FadeInImage.
I ave added the hyperlinks in the images and generating the list of images after hitting the API.

```
child: Hero(
                tag: tag,
                child: FadeInImage(
                  width: 130.0,
                  height: 186.0,
                  placeholder: AssetImage('assets/images/splash1.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,

                  // onTap: _launchUrl(),

                  image: NetworkImage(
                      (merchant.logo)),
                  // fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

when I run my app, the images are not loaded; the screen is empty. But when I hot reload it shows.

```
 ...List.generate(
            merchantsList.length,
            (index) {
              print(merchantsList.length);
              print(index);

              return MerchantCard(merchant: merchantsList[index]);
```

Comment: are you calling setstate after generating ?

Comment: No I don't have setSate in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually widget was built before values are populated in the list. I used setState on my listPopulated function and it worked perfectly ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can use placeholder image and also you can add Future Builder concept and Please once check the Future Concept.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new FutureBuilder(
   future: _loadImage(),
   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Image> image) {
   if (image.hasData) {
    return image.data;  // image is ready
   } else {
    return new Container();  // placeholder
     }
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: I got this,"Another exception was thrown: type 'NetworkImage' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Image>?' where"